# SQL assign a value to a variable but taking that value from another row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the Superior_Val to be equal to 'Value' of the next year, like:

```
Year    Value    Superior_Val
0       0.1      0.3
1       0.3      0.7
2       0.7      1.6
3       1.6
```

How can I make it work something like (This is erroneous but it's just to understand the goal I want to achieve):

```
Superior_Val=Value where Year=Year+1
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*, lead(value) over (order by year) as next_value
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, if year is reliable then a self join

```
select a.year,a.value, b.value
from  t a
left join t b on b.year = a.year + 1
```